# JS: Put text from button attribute to div

Tags: javascript

I need to put text from attribute "dataset" in button into a div.

```js
var buttons=document.querySelectorAll("button");
console.log(buttons);
var div=document.querySelector("div");
console.log(div);

for (i=0; i<buttons.length;i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    buttons[i].dataset.text=div.innerText;
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="container">  </div><br>
<button data-text="Button text 1">Click me!</button>
<button data-text="Button text 2">Click me!</button>
<button data-text="Button text 3">Click me!</button>
```

Result in console:

> Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

HTML `button`s does not have the attribute `dataset`. To set the value of an attribute:

```
buttons[i].setAttribute('data-text', 'your-string-goes-here');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAttribute()` to get the attribute `data-text` and attach it to your div on button click.

```js
var buttons=document.querySelectorAll("button");
var div=document.querySelector("div");

for (var i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
  (function (i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
      div.innerText = buttons[i].getAttribute('data-text');
    })
   })(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">  </div><br>
<button data-text="Button text 1">Click me!</button>
<button data-text="Button text 2">Click me!</button>
<button data-text="Button text 3">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Hassan, that's what i ment! :)